# Connecting Jconsole to eclipse based aplication

Tags: eclipse, jmx, jconsole

I am having the desktop application based on the eclipse framework. Just wanted to know the way to configure it with jmx so that I can monitor it using the jconsole. Unable to find any documentation for that. Could someone provide the required steps and configuration I am supposed to do to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a read through [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html). There is even a section titled [Using JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html).